# Restrict world access to Amazon S3 URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've configured an S3 bucket with CloudFront and using alternate domain name provided by CludFront (I setup the domain alias images.mydomain.com at my DNS zone file).
At my DNS host the CNAME I'm pointing to xyz.cloudfront.net. Both my s3 bucket name and CNAME domain alias are images.mydomain.com.

I want world to access my images at images.mydomain.com/image.jpg and this is working perfectly.

The problem is the same resource is directly accessible by the world via below two URLs too and I don't want this to happen. I want only images.mydomain.com/image.jpg to work for world and not the below two.

images.mydomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com/image.jpg
s3.amazonaws.com/images.mydomain.com/image.jpg

How do I achieve this? please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html

> You restrict access to Amazon S3 content by creating an origin access
>   identity, which is a special CloudFront user. You change Amazon S3
>   permissions to give the origin access identity permission to access
>   your objects, and to remove permissions from everyone else. When your
>   users access your Amazon S3 objects using CloudFront URLs, the
>   CloudFront origin access identity gets the objects on your users'
>   behalf. If your users try to access objects using Amazon S3 URLs,
>   they're denied access. The origin access identity has permission to
>   access objects in your Amazon S3 bucket, but users don't.

Comment: I've done exactly what you've explained and in fact I followed the same resource you are referencing. The other two URLs are still working. Do I have to wait a certain amount of time before this happens. Below is my policy for the s3 bucket:
`
{
 "Version": "2008-10-17",
 "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "1",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ***************"
   },
   "Action": "s3:GetObject",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::images.mydomain.com/*"
  }
 ]
}
`

Comment: also, when I'm creating the CNAME record at my DNS host should I use cloudfront domain name (xyz.cloudfront.net) or the s3 path (images.mydomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com)? which is correct?

Comment: New policy I have created for my S3 bucket still not working:
`
{
 "Id": "Policy1419249708936",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "Stmt************",
   "Action": "s3:*",
   "Effect": "Deny",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::images.mydomain.com/*",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
     "*"
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "Sid": "Stmt************",
   "Action": [
    "s3:GetObject"
   ],
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::images.mydomain.com/*",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
     "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity **************"
    ]
   }
  }
 ]
}
`

Comment: After deleting all buckets, IAM users and cloudfront distributions I had created while working towards achieving the above I created a new bucket and then created a cloudfront distribution to use the new bucket and everything worked fine. Tank you for your help @E.J. Brenan

Comment: @user3708270 so what was the problem ? I'm having the same issue, it just worked after deleting all your buckets ?